# How to detect if an sdcard or mount point will mount as removable storage or MTP?

Tags: android

When an android phone is connected to a computer with a USB cable it may mount as removable storage but some phones might mount it as mtp (media transfer protocol) is there a way to detect this in android whether a sdcard will mount as removable or mtp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

to see if the external storage is mounted and you can use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED);
```

to see if it is removed completely. You will find all the different cases you need in the Environment class.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the question .. how does the above code tell me its is mounted as mtp ? or disk drive ?

Comment: Look inside http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html seems like you want to get the states MEDIA_SHARED and MEDIA_MOUNTED